# How to trigger 500 Internal Server Error in PHP on a Windows Server

Tags: php, error-handling, windows-server-2012

I'm trying to trigger a 500 error on a PHP site in order to add a custom 500 error page. Iv'e tried lots of examples from stack overflow. It's IIS on windows server 2012, Has anyone tried this before?

Thank you,
Conor

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger a 500 internal exception with the following header:

```
header("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error");
die;
```